# Making permutations in string based on a pattern

Tags: python, python-itertools

Input List: (only if index[1] is having / )

```
['A', 'dog,big/small;rat,big/small', '12', '21']
```

Return List:

```
['A', 'dog,big;rat,big', '12', '21']
['A', 'dog,small;rat,big', '12', '21']
['A', 'dog,big;rat,small', '12', '21']
['A', 'dog,small;rat,small', '12', '21']
```

Comment: What have you tried?  I don't see a Stack Overflow-type question here.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one should work for general input-strings of that type:

```
def permute(s):
    a, b = s.split(',')
    return [a + "," + c for c in b.split('/')]

def traverse(s):
    parts = s.split(';', 1)
    if len(parts) == 1:
        return permute(s)
    else:
        return sum([[k + ';' + l for l in traverse(parts[1])] for k in permute(parts[0])], [])

for s in traverse('dog,big/small;rat,big/small'):
    print ['A', s, '12', '21']
```